# Chamando função em um controller a partir de um parametro enviado pelo usuário em PHP

Tags: php

Estou construindo uma aplicação que, a partir da informação que o usuário me enviar em um GET eu vou executar uma função. EX:

```
//classe
class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public class index($param){ 
      //aqui estou procurando algo semelhante a $this->"$param"();
    }

    private class foo(){ echo 'foo'; }
    private class bar(){ echo 'bar'; }

}
```

Pelo exemplo acima, se o meu usuário enviasse para a função `index('foo')` ele teria que executar a função `$this->foo()`. Alguém poderia me mostrar como consigo fazer minha função `index()` executar outra função dependendo do parâmetro enviado?

Comment: Você precisa criar rotas para sua aplicação, o controller não deve ser responsável por direcionar ações que não sejam redirecionamentos em casos isolados. Aqui tem um exemplo: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing - É um pouco chato de se fazer sem framework, mas é possível, eu tenho um sistema de rotas que fiz pra uso próprio e funciona tão bem quanto aos dos frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Para você fazer isso é simples.

Vamos criar um controller chamado por exemplo **teste** e dentro dele fazer o que você precisa:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Teste extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function ver($param){
        echo $this->$param();
    }
    private function foo(){
        echo 'foo';
    }
}
```

Acesse a URL e passe o o comando, como exemplo:

http://localhost/teste/ver/foo

Irá exibir

```
foo
```

caso você queira criar um controller para controlar toda aplicação e deixar a URL organizada, você poderá utilizar `Rotas`, que é uma saida boa e fácil:

http://codeigniterbrasil.com/configuracoes/configuracao-rotas-routes-codeigniter/